# Manage multiple projects for reuse

Tags: workflow

I hope "projects" is the correct word. I have some blend files like

```
character.blend
room.blend
```

The character is rigged and has 2 animations (walking, running) stored in the file `character.blend`. I export the `character.blend` to `character.fbx` and import it into `room.blend`.

The animations are made only using rotations so i have just saved the `Rotation`. I saved them as actions.

When I import the `character.fbx` file into `room.blend`, move the character to its desired location and play an action he plays the action but the character also jumps to the location where it was initially imported and I can see in the action editor that the action got `location` indexes as well but I haven't stored them. My knowledge is that I can store actions in the file `character.fbx` so I don't have to recreate them every time I use the character in another file.

Am I using actions/animations the correct way?

Comment: Why would you export your character to fbx and import it into another .blend file in the first place? You can use Blender's append functionality for that.